# M4: How to drop leading whitespace from script followed by file?

Tags: bash, m4

If I have an `m4` script with many commands:

```
define(this, that)
define(or,this)
define(other,thing)
```

And I call:

```
$: m4 script.m4 my_file
```

The output is:

```
# N newlines for the N commands in the script
# first line of my file
```

Is it possible to suppress the `N newlines` resulting from the script read-in when calling `m4`, or do I have to wrap this in some set of calling commands (like `sed` or `grep`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dnl` macro to delete new lines for `define`s. E.g. from [this tutorial](https://mbreen.com/m4.html):

> The define macro itself – including its two arguments – expands to an
>   empty string, that is, it produces no output. However the newline at
>   the end of the AUTHOR definition above would be echoed to the output.
>   If a blank line added to the output is a problem then you can suppress
>   it using the “delete to newline” macro:
>
> ```
>  define(AUTHOR, W. Shakespeare)dnl
> ```
>
> There is no space between the end of the macro and the dnl: if there were
>   then that space would be echoed to the output.